# Another, $E$ bounded above, show that there is a sequence $(a_n) \subset E$ such that $a_n \to \sup E$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be an infinite set of real numbers which is bounded above. Show that there exists a sequence $( a_n ) \subset E$ such that $\lim a_n = \sup E$ if $\sup E \not \in E$.

I asked this question before but I want to know if there is a way to prove this without knowing the fact that, by definition of supremum, for each $n\ge1$ there exists an element $y\in E$ such that $y>\sup E-\frac1n$.

My attempt:

Since $E$ is bounded above, $\sup E<\infty $. Writing $\lim a_n = \sup E$ is the same as saying that $a_n$ converges to $sup E$. By definition, if a sequence converges, it is also a cauchy sequence.

I dont know where to go from there and I don't know if i am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If $s=\sup E\notin E$, $s$ must be an accumulation point and exist, for every $\epsilon=1/k$, an element $a_k\in E$ such that $a_k\in (s-1/k,s)$, and then $a_k\to s$.

Comment: what's an accumulation point?

Comment: @combostudent: It is a point such that every neighborhood contains infinitely many of the points in your sequence.

Comment: @combostudent A point x\in E such that for every e>0, (x-e,x+e)\cap E\neq \emptyset